# Does returning my I-94 at the Canadian border make any difference at all?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, i-94

When returning from the US to Canada by land, you have the option to return your I-94 to the CBSA official. However this seems to be a bit useless as nowadays all exits are automatically (and nearly instantly) recorded and passed on to DHS, whether or not you return the I-94 paper. Likewise returning your I-94 [doesn't reset the I-94 status](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108843/why-wasnt-i-issued-a-new-i-94-after-previously-having-had-returned-one-at-the-c), so you would still be admitted under your previous I-94 on the next visit to the US.

So the question - does it make any sense at all to bother returning the I-94? Does it change anything at all as far as US immigration officials are concerned?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't once, and I got told off.

I was on Greyhound back into Canada, and they just cruised on through, easily, without handing in anything.

Then the next time I was entering the US, he opened to see my I-94 slip.  He got quite vocal about how I was meant to return this, I apologised and he just shrugged and shoved it in a drawer with many, many more.

The next time I crossed the border, I insisted that I give mine to the Canadian border guy, who seemed a bit bemused, but took it anyway.

Short version: I did this, got a telling off, that was the extent of it.