# Is there a legal obligation to surrender the I-94 when leaving to Canada overland?

Tags: usa, legal, i-94

The [paper version](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2018-Mar/700120%20-%20CBP%20Form%20I-94W%20ENG%20%281216%29%20-%20FINAL%20%28SAMPLE%29.pdf) of I-94 says the following:

> Retain this permit in your possession; **you must surrender it** when you leave the U.S. Failure to do so may delay your entry into the U.S. in the future.

However [in practice](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109383/does-returning-my-i-94-at-the-canadian-border-make-any-difference-at-all), your exit is always recorded when you enter Canada overland as the two countries [share immigration data](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/btb-pdf/ebsiip-asfipi-eng.html). Therefore presuming that your exit was properly recorded, is there also a legal obligation to return the physical I-94 paper to Canadian immigration?

Please cite the relevant sections of US immigration law, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've [emailed CBP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/ask) to clarify this question and received the following response:

> Hello,
>
> If your departure was recorded on our official website, then
> no further action is required.
>
> Regards, Traveler Communications
> Center

Therefore there does not seem to be an official requirement to surrender the I-94.